# SQL Server 2014 In-Memory OLTP. SELECT statement speed

Tags: database-performance, in-memory-database, sql-server-2014

I'm analyzing SQL Server 2014 In-Memory OLTP feature and faced to situation that SELECT statement elapsed time is identical between in-memory and physical tables.

I know that In-Memory feature mainly impacts insert/delete operations where no latching/locking take part.

But I'm interested why access time to RAM and physical disk is the same even without latching/locking in the case of reading data.

Can anyone give me logical answer to this and whether it cannot be improved ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always think about caching and the buffer pool. If your in-memory table data is in memory and your on-disk table data is in memory, should you really expect it to be any faster? Possibly at a very low level but unlikely to be observable by the human brain until you are at a very high level of concurrency.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The think is I clean up buffer pool of on-disk table and get the same result.

Comment: So how big is your table? How much memory do you have? Is data on SSD? Again, a lot of factors here but I would not expect improvement on singleton queries run in isolation. Especially if the data is small and/or resides on fast disk. I also don't know what meaning you get from comparing to cold (not yet cached) tables. How often will your system really be in this state?

Comment: Tried on different number of rows in table (1, 10, 20, 30 millions). Tried with memory = 16 GB. Data is on SDD. There is no meaning with comparing to cold table. Just wanted to see if the identical time due to caching, but with or without cache the time is the same.

Comment: SSD isn't as fast as memory, but it's pretty close. If you want to see a difference, I suggest putting your data on a slow disk or test with much, much higher concurrency (like real world concurrency using hammerdb or other stressing tools, not two queries from SSMS).